# OSX Mono Develop 2.8.5 Crashes When Starting New Solution

Tags: macos, mono, monodevelop

I am currently running OS X 10.5.8 with MonoDevelop 2.8.5 with Mono Framework Version 2.10.8. When I start MonoDevelop and select Start New Solution the IDE will always crash. If I simply a file the file will open in the IDE.

I have reinstalled MonoDevelop and the Framework with no luck. I have not found anything via web searches that relate to my issue. Below the log output. Does anyone have any clue how to fix this?

**System Properties**

```
MonoDevelop 2.8.5
    Installation UUID: fc95e309-1acd-4f55-8f9f-b1a74a72cb08
    Runtime:
        Mono 2.10.8 (tarball Mon Dec 19 17:43:18 EST 2011)
        GTK 2.24.5
        GTK# (2.12.0.0)
    Apple Developer Tools:
        (Not Found)

Monotouch: 
Mono for Android not installed
Build information:
    Release ID: 20805000
    Git revision: c4deb930539ae87247b0bc43919dfcb98df215c2
    Build date: 2011-12-09 23:27:52+0000
Operating System:
    Mac OS X 10.5.8
    Darwin iMac.local 9.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.8.0: Wed Jul 15 16:55:01 PDT 2009; root:xnu-1228.15.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
Loaded assemblies:
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib     2.84.0.0 /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib/2.84.0.0__1b03e6acf1164f73/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll
MonoDevelop.GtkCore         2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/MonoDevelop.GtkCore.dll
libsteticui                 0.0.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/libsteticui.dll
libstetic                   0.0.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/libstetic.dll
Mono.Security               4.0.0.0  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll
Xamarin.Ide.Mac             1.0.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Ide.Mac.dll
nunit.util                  2.4.8.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/NUnit/nunit.util.dll
nunit.framework             2.4.8.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/NUnit/nunit.framework.dll
nunit.core.interfaces       2.4.8.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/NUnit/nunit.core.interfaces.dll
nunit.core                  2.4.8.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/NUnit/nunit.core.dll
MonoDevelop.NUnit           2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/NUnit/MonoDevelop.NUnit.dll
Mono.Cairo                  4.0.0.0  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Cairo/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Cairo.dll
MonoDeveloperExtensions     2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDeveloperExtensions/MonoDeveloperExtensions.dll
Mono.Debugging              0.0.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/bin/Mono.Debugging.dll
pango-sharp                 2.12.0.0 /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/pango-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/pango-sharp.dll
monodoc                     1.0.0.0  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/monodoc/1.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/monodoc.dll
MonoDevelop.Moonlight       2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.Moonlight/MonoDevelop.Moonlight.dll
MonoDevelop.AspNet          2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.AspNet/MonoDevelop.AspNet.dll
MonoDevelop.XmlEditor       2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.XmlEditor/MonoDevelop.XmlEditor.dll
MonoDevelop.Deployment      2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.Deployment/MonoDevelop.Deployment.dll
System.Drawing              4.0.0.0  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
Mono.Cecil                  0.9.4.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/bin/Mono.Cecil.dll
MonoDevelop.MonoDroid       4.0.0.24 /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.dll
Mono.AndroidTools           0.9.3.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/Mono.AndroidTools.dll
MonoDevelop.IPhone          2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.IPhone/MonoDevelop.IPhone.dll
MonoDevelop.MacDev          2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MacDev/MonoDevelop.MacDev.dll
MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport 2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport/MonoDevelop.DesignerSupport.dll
MacPlatform                 2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MacPlatform.dll
MonoMac                     0.0.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoMac.dll
MonoDevelop.VersionControl  2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.dll
MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2   2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2.dll
MonoDevelop.Debugger        2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.Debugger/MonoDevelop.Debugger.dll
Xamarin.Ide                 1.0.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Ide.dll
System.Configuration        4.0.0.0  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
gdk-sharp                   2.12.0.0 /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/gdk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gdk-sharp.dll
Mono.TextEditor             1.0.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/bin/Mono.TextEditor.dll
atk-sharp                   2.12.0.0 /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/atk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/atk-sharp.dll
gtk-sharp                   2.12.0.0 /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/gtk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gtk-sharp.dll
Mono.Posix                  4.0.0.0  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Posix/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Posix.dll
Mono.Addins                 0.6.0.0  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Addins/0.6.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Addins.dll
Mono.Addins.Setup           0.6.0.0  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Addins.Setup/0.6.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Addins.Setup.dll
System.Xml                  4.0.0.0  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
System.Xml.Linq             4.0.0.0  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml.Linq/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
System.Core                 4.0.0.0  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
glib-sharp                  2.12.0.0 /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/glib-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/glib-sharp.dll
System                      4.0.0.0  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
MonoDevelop.Core            2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.Core.dll
MonoDevelop.Ide             2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.Ide.dll
MonoDevelop                 2.6.0.0  /Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/bin/MonoDevelop.exe
mscorlib                    4.0.0.0  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.8/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll
```

---

**Stack Trace**

```
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoDevelop.Core.FileSystem.UnixFileSystemExtension.realpath (string,intptr) <IL 0x00047, 0xffffffff>
  at MonoDevelop.Core.FileSystem.UnixFileSystemExtension.ResolveFullPath (MonoDevelop.Core.FilePath) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core.FileSystem/UnixFileSystemExtension.cs:41
  at MonoDevelop.Core.FileService.ResolveFullPath (MonoDevelop.Core.FilePath) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core/FileService.cs:93
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects.NewProjectDialog.InitializeComponents () [0x00100] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects/NewProjectDialog.cs:551
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects.NewProjectDialog.InitializeTemplates () [0x00143] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects/NewProjectDialog.cs:615
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects.NewProjectDialog..ctor (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionFolder,bool,string) [0x000d3] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects/NewProjectDialog.cs:91
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.ProjectOperations.NewSolution (string) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/ProjectOperations.cs:627
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.ProjectOperations.NewSolution () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/ProjectOperations.cs:622
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.NewProjectHandler.Run () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands/FileCommands.cs:137
  at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandHandler.Run (object) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Components.Commands/CommandHandler.cs:61
  at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandHandler.InternalRun (object) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Components.Commands/CommandHandler.cs:42
  at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandManager.DefaultDispatchCommand (MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.ActionCommand,MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandInfo,object,object,MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandSource) [0x00076] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Components.Commands/CommandManager.cs:696
  at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandManager.DispatchCommand (object,object,object,MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandSource) [0x002d1] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Components.Commands/CommandManager.cs:666
  at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandManager.DispatchCommand (object,MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandSource) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Components.Commands/CommandManager.cs:565
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.WelcomePage.WelcomePageLinkButton.DispatchLink (string) [0x0007d] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.WelcomePage/WelcomePageLinkButton.cs:214
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.WelcomePage.WelcomePageLinkButton.OnClicked () [0x00006] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.WelcomePage/WelcomePageLinkButton.cs:199
  at Gtk.Button.clicked_cb (intptr) <IL 0x0000e, 0x00059>
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) Gtk.Button.clicked_cb (intptr) <IL 0x0001d, 0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gtk.Application.gtk_main () <IL 0x00022, 0xffffffff>
  at Gtk.Application.Run () <IL 0x00000, 0x0000b>
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Run () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/Ide.cs:384
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run (MonoDevelop.Ide.MonoDevelopOptions) [0x006ac] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:275
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main (string[]) [0x0005e] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:542
  at MonoDevelop.Startup.MonoDevelopMain.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Startup/MonoDevelop.Startup/MonoDevelopMain.cs:16
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_int_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0005c, 0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

        0   monodevelop                         0x00094efc mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
        1   monodevelop                         0x00004fe8 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 248
        2   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x962f21cb _sigtramp + 43
        3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
        4   ???                                 0x1c521278 0x0 + 475140728
        5   ???                                 0x1c52120c 0x0 + 475140620
        6   ???                                 0x1c520f09 0x0 + 475139849
        7   ???                                 0x1c51f508 0x0 + 475133192
        8   ???                                 0x1c643f40 0x0 + 476331840
        9   ???                                 0x1c63eb38 0x0 + 476310328
        10  ???                                 0x1c63e928 0x0 + 476309800
        11  ???                                 0x1c63e8ec 0x0 + 476309740
        12  ???                                 0x1c63e8c0 0x0 + 476309696
        13  ???                                 0x1c3c82ac 0x0 + 473727660
        14  ???                                 0x1c3c828f 0x0 + 473727631
        15  ???                                 0x1c3c8054 0x0 + 473727060
        16  ???                                 0x1c3c7c40 0x0 + 473726016
        17  ???                                 0x1c3c7644 0x0 + 473724484
        18  ???                                 0x1c3c757c 0x0 + 473724284
        19  ???                                 0x1c3c7380 0x0 + 473723776
        20  ???                                 0x1c3c7312 0x0 + 473723666
        21  ???                                 0x1bff1670 0x0 + 469702256
        22  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022e461c g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__VOID + 164
        23  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022cac44 g_cclosure_new_swap + 316
        24  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022ca93b g_closure_invoke + 370
        25  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022e359d g_signal_emit_by_name + 1801
        26  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022e2b6c g_signal_emit_valist + 2212
        27  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022e2e92 g_signal_emit + 44
        28  libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib           0x0235accf gtk_button_clicked + 191
        29  libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib           0x0235c547 gtk_button_get_relief + 5559
        30  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022e461c g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__VOID + 164
        31  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022cac44 g_cclosure_new_swap + 316
        32  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022ca93b g_closure_invoke + 370
        33  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022e359d g_signal_emit_by_name + 1801
        34  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022e2b6c g_signal_emit_valist + 2212
        35  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022e2e92 g_signal_emit + 44
        36  libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib           0x0235abff gtk_button_released + 191
        37  libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib           0x0235c23e gtk_button_get_relief + 4782
        38  libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib           0x0245a68e gtk_marshal_VOID__UINT_STRING + 542
        39  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022cac44 g_cclosure_new_swap + 316
        40  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022ca93b g_closure_invoke + 370
        41  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022e3c86 g_signal_emit_by_name + 3570
        42  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022e2be6 g_signal_emit_valist + 2334
        43  libgobject-2.0.0.dylib              0x022e2e92 g_signal_emit + 44
        44  libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib           0x026004b9 gtk_widget_send_expose + 1353
        45  libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib           0x025fff4f gtk_widget_event + 319
        46  libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib           0x0245868e gtk_propagate_event + 654
        47  libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib           0x02456c1a gtk_main_do_event + 1098
        48  libgdk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib           0x028a38f9 pollfds_equal + 2265
        49  libglib-2.0.0.dylib                 0x0219f58d g_source_is_destroyed + 843
        50  libglib-2.0.0.dylib                 0x021a0bf7 g_main_context_dispatch + 144
        51  libglib-2.0.0.dylib                 0x021a113b g_main_context_dispatch + 1492
        52  libglib-2.0.0.dylib                 0x021a1987 g_main_loop_run + 992
        53  libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib           0x024560c0 gtk_main + 240
        54  ???                                 0x1c31516c 0x0 + 472994156
        55  ???                                 0x1c315134 0x0 + 472994100
        56  ???                                 0x1c315114 0x0 + 472994068
        57  ???                                 0x02155060 0x0 + 34951264
        58  ???                                 0x00481f98 0x0 + 4726680
        59  ???                                 0x00481d9c 0x0 + 4726172
        60  ???                                 0x00481e56 0x0 + 4726358
        61  monodevelop                         0x0000d282 mono_jit_compile_method + 850
        62  monodevelop                         0x001a436a mono_runtime_invoke + 170
        63  monodevelop                         0x001a6eac mono_runtime_exec_main + 620
        64  monodevelop                         0x001a6111 mono_runtime_run_main + 929
        65  monodevelop                         0x00069995 mono_jit_exec + 149
        66  monodevelop                         0x0006bf13 mono_main + 9587
        67  monodevelop                         0x00002299 main + 441
        68  monodevelop                         0x000020a6 start + 54

Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it might be fixed by this commit:
https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/commit/b28011d5ede39304e7d74003870e93eb23af5cc6

In theory the crash should be random, but if you're unlucky it could be consistent. I'd suggest downgrading to MD 2.8.4 (at least for creating new solutions) until 2.8.6 is released.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I couldn't find a link to download MonoDevelop 2.8.4 so I tried the beta of 2.9.1. That fixed the issue above however it always crashes on closing. Do you know where I can get the installer for 2.8.4?

Comment: There isn't a published link but you can go to monodevelop.com/Download to get the current download link then alter it to get the old version.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally got it to work. Here is the link if anyone has the same issue, http://download.xamarin.com/monodevelop/Mac/MonoDevelop-2.8.4.dmg.